# Remove child element is exist in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

```
removeConnection(event)
{ 
 
    let parentElement = document.getElementById('RemoveElement');
    let childElement = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    parentElement.removeChild(childElement);
  
}
```

i want to delete the child elelment from parent but when i do this then child element is not deleted and it exist in body and show in screen.

here is the hirerachy of html body

```
<div id="RemoveElement" style="overflow: hidden; width: 350px; height: 350px; position: absolute; top: 15px; pointer-events: none;">
   <div class="label" id="mesh_4" draggable="false" style="margin-top: -1em; pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; user-select: none; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(204.578px, 255.514px); z-index: 1;">+</div>
   <div class="label" id="mesh_18" draggable="false" style="margin-top: -1em; pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; user-select: none; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(148.623px, 64.7255px); z-index: 2;">+</div>
</div>




  console.log(childModel.name);
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'label';
    div.textContent = '+';
    div.type='button';
    div.id=childModel.name;
    div.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  
    div.addEventListener("pointerdown",scope_AC.uiHandler.removeConnection,false);
    let label = new CSS2DObject( div );
    childModel.add( label );
    label.position.copy(pos);
    

    scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.setSize( 350, 350 );
    scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '15px';
    scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement.id = 'RemoveElement';  document.body.appendChild(scope_AC.modeler.labelRenderer.domElement);
```

Comment: It's hard to determine what's going on without seeing your html and how the function is called.

Comment: How/when do you call `RemoveConnection()`?

Comment: when annotation button clicked then remove function called.

Comment: even this functionality works as I check in debugger but without debugger button doesn't be remove

Comment: What is `annotation button`? The code here does not call your function anywhere. What debugger are you using?

Comment: as you can see i create button dynamically on model which i code mentioned above so when i remove the specific button then it will remove in inspect element debugger but after button will not be removed without testing

Comment: Your code here is hard to follow.  What are `childModel`, `scope_AC`, `CSS2DObject`, etc.? When is the second group of JS called?

Comment: its basically a code of embedded in three.js .child model is where button is attached, scope_Ac is the var of other script and css2dobject is the library part of three.js which you make a 2d button or element in scene

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an object from its parent with `parent.remove(chlid);`, as [outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.remove).

You're adding your object with the following:

```js
let label = new CSS2DObject( div );
childModel.add( label );
```

so to remove it, just do the opposite:

```js
childModel.remove( label );
```